# How to use SVG markers in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, svg

Can I use my converted image.svg as google map icon. I was converting my png image to svg and I want to use this like google map symbol that can be rotated. I already tried to use the google map symbol but I want to have an icon like car, man, etc... That's why I converted my some png files to svg, just like this example site what does he use for these http://www.goprotravelling.com/

Comment: For those searching for this similar question: a partial IE 9+ compatible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30890373/634386 will place an SVG in the DOM instead of on the canvas so that you can manipulate with CSS3 after (if you're looking to rotate that element specifically on the fly).

Comment: if you have many markers on your map, its recommended to use png rastered ones https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/google-maps-platform-best-practices-optimization-and-performance-tips

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You can render your icon using the [SVG Path notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths).

See [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols) for more information.

Here is a basic example:

```
var icon = {

    path: "M-20,0a20,20 0 1,0 40,0a20,20 0 1,0 -40,0",
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: .6,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    strokeWeight: 0,
    scale: 1
}

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    icon: icon
});
```

Here is a working example on how to display and scale a marker SVG icon:

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/88JLY/)

**Edit:**

Another example here with a complex icon:

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/eLcNq/)

**Edit 2:**

And here is how you can have a SVG file as an icon:

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/r1mm0hft/)

Comment: ,it's very difficult to make car svg.

Comment: Do you have a SVG image of that car you want? Then just open it with a text editor and find the path in it!

Comment: SVG is usually used for icons and other symbols. One color. It's just a path, like a letter in a font. The advantages is that you can easily scale it, rotate it and change its color, without losing quality. It's a vector shape.

Comment: @MrUpsidown How can I take a complex svg image and break it down into path notation like you did in your complex example? Particularly when I have paths nested inside of paths?

Comment: @E.E.33 There are tools for that. Inkscape, Illustrator can be helpful. Also, try to open your SVG file with a text editor (notepad, Sublime text, etc.) and you will see what you can find in it ;)

Answer (score 86):

If you need a full svg not only a path and you want it to be modifiable on client side (e.g. change text, hide details, ...) you can use an alternative data 'URL' with included svg:

```
var svg = '<svg width="400" height="110"><rect width="300" height="100" /></svg>';
icon.url = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8;base64,' + btoa(svg);
```

JavaScript (Firefox) btoa() is used to get the base64 encoding from the SVG text. Your may also use http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php to generate base data URLs.

Here is a full example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttLu41ok/128):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var template = [
                '<?xml version="1.0"?>',
                    '<svg width="26px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">',
                        '<circle stroke="#222" fill="{{ color }}" cx="50" cy="50" r="35"/>',
                    '</svg>'
                ].join('\n');
            var svg = template.replace('{{ color }}', '#800');

            var docMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
                map: map,
                title: 'Dynamic SVG Marker',
                icon: { url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svg), scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20) },
optimized: false
            });

            var docMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.95, 151.25),
                map: map,
                title: 'Dynamic SVG Marker',
                icon: { url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8;base64,' + btoa(svg), scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20) },
optimized: false
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Additional Information can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6505).

**Avoid base64 encoding:**

In order to avoid base64 encoding you can replace `'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8;base64,' + btoa(svg)` with `'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svg)`

This should work with modern browsers down to IE9.
The advantage is that `encodeURIComponent` is a default js function and available in all modern browsers. You might also get smaller links but you need to test this and consider to use `'` instead of `"` in your svg.

Also see [Optimizing SVGs in data URIs](http://codepen.io/Tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris) for additional info.

**IE support:**
In order to support SVG Markers in IE one needs two small adaptions as described here: [SVG Markers in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414387/google-maps-svg-marker-doesnt-display-on-ie-11). I updated the example code to support IE.

Comment: Good info, but quick note that base64 encoding isn't actually necessary or desirable. You can use svg encoding directly in the data URI instead, like `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,`. More info: https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/

Comment: You are right it would be great if we could avoid the base64 encoding. How did you do it could you provide an example? If I just add the svg code to the URI it doesn't work with some chars like `#` did you use URL encoding?

Comment: I should mention it's utf8 encoded; svg is the format. The link provided has several examples.

Comment: How to use rotate svg image by using this?

Comment: Don't we all love IE ;) As usual it requires some additional work to make it work on all browsers. I adapted the example to support IE, hope this helps.

Comment: The google maps team uses this same method for the default icons like street view, zoom in, zoom out, full screen, etc.

Answer (score 37):

I know this post is a bit old, but I have seen so much bad information on this at SO that I could scream. So I just gotta throw my two cents in with a whole different approach that I know works, as I use it reliably on many maps. Besides that, I believe the OP wanted the ability to rotate the arrow marker around the map point as well, which is different than rotating the icon around it's own x,y axis which will change where the arrow marker points to on the map.

First, remember we are playing with Google maps and SVG, so we must accomodate the way in which Google deploys it's implementation of SVG for markers (or actually symbols). Google sets its anchor for the SVG marker image at 0,0 which IS NOT the upper left corner of the SVG viewBox. In order to get around this, you must draw your SVG image a bit differently to give Google what it wants... yes the answer is in the way you actually create the SVG path in your SVG editor (Illustrator, Inkscape, etc...).

The first step, is to get rid of the viewBox. This can be done by setting the viewBox in your XML to 0... that's right, just one zero instead of the usual four arguments for the viewBox. This turns the view box off (and yes, this is semantically correct). You will probably notice the size of your image jump immeadiately when you do this, and that is because the svg no longer has a base (the viewBox) to scale the image. So we create that reference directly, by setting the width and height to the actual number of pixels you wish your image to be in the XML editor of your SVG editor.

By setting the width and height of the svg image in the XML editor you create a baseline for scaling of the image, and this size becomes a value of 1 for the marker scale properties by default. You can see the advantage this has for dynamic scaling of the marker.

Now that you have your image sized, move the image until the part of the image you wish to have as the anchor is over the 0,0 coordinates of the svg editor. Once you have done this copy the value of the ***d*** attribute of the svg path. You will notice about half of the numbers are negative, which is the result of aligning your anchor point for the 0,0 of the image instead of the viewBox.

Using this technique will then let you rotate the marker correctly, around the lat and lng point on the map. This is the only reliable way to bind the point on the svg marker you want to the lat and long of the marker location.

I tried to make [**a JSFiddle for this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ephiphany/beyL0jn9/), but there is some bug in there implementation, one of the reasons I am not so fond of reinterpreted code. So instead, I have included a fully self-contained example below that you can try out, adapt, and use as a reference. This is the same code I tried at JSFiddle that failed, yet it sails through Firebug without a whimper.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="author"    content="Drew G. Stimson, Sr. ( Epiphany )" />
    <title>Create Draggable and Rotatable SVG Marker</title>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #document_body {
        margin:0;
        border: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #f0f9f9;
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
        background:#1f1f1f;
      }
      #map_canvas, #rotation_control {
        margin: 1px;
        border:1px solid #000;
        background:#444;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
           -moz-border-radius: 4px;
                border-radius: 4px;
      }
      #map_canvas { 
        width: 100%;
        height: 360px;
      }
      #rotation_control { 
        width: auto;
        padding:5px;
      }
      #rotation_value { 
        margin: 1px;
        border:1px solid #999;
        width: 60px;
        padding:2px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #00cc00;
        text-align: center;
        background:#111;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var map, arrow_marker, arrow_options;
  var map_center = {lat:41.0, lng:-103.0};
  var arrow_icon = {
    path: 'M -1.1500216e-4,0 C 0.281648,0 0.547084,-0.13447 0.718801,-0.36481 l 17.093151,-22.89064 c 0.125766,-0.16746 0.188044,-0.36854 0.188044,-0.56899 0,-0.19797 -0.06107,-0.39532 -0.182601,-0.56215 -0.245484,-0.33555 -0.678404,-0.46068 -1.057513,-0.30629 l -11.318243,4.60303 0,-26.97635 C 5.441639,-47.58228 5.035926,-48 4.534681,-48 l -9.06959,0 c -0.501246,0 -0.906959,0.41772 -0.906959,0.9338 l 0,26.97635 -11.317637,-4.60303 c -0.379109,-0.15439 -0.812031,-0.0286 -1.057515,0.30629 -0.245483,0.33492 -0.244275,0.79809 0.0055,1.13114 L -0.718973,-0.36481 C -0.547255,-0.13509 -0.281818,0 -5.7002158e-5,0 Z',
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#fefe99',
    fillOpacity: 1,
    rotation: 0,
    scale: 1.0
  };

function init(){
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: map_center,
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  });
  arrow_options = {
    position: map_center,
    icon: arrow_icon,
    clickable: false,
    draggable: true,
    crossOnDrag: true,
    visible: true,
    animation: 0,
    title: 'I am a Draggable-Rotatable Marker!' 
  };
  arrow_marker = new google.maps.Marker(arrow_options);
  arrow_marker.setMap(map);
}
function setRotation(){
  var heading = parseInt(document.getElementById('rotation_value').value);
  if (isNaN(heading)) heading = 0;
  if (heading < 0) heading = 359;
  if (heading > 359) heading = 0;
  arrow_icon.rotation = heading;
  arrow_marker.setOptions({icon:arrow_icon});
  document.getElementById('rotation_value').value = heading;
}
</script>
</head>
<body id="document_body" onload="init();">
  <div id="rotation_control">
    <small>Enter heading to rotate marker&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</small>
    Heading&deg;<input id="rotation_value" type="number" size="3" value="0" onchange="setRotation();" />
    <small>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Drag marker to place marker</small>
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is exactly what Google does for it's own few symbols available in the SYMBOL class of the Maps API, so if that doesn't convince you...
Anyway, I hope this will help you to correctly make and set up a SVG marker for your Google maps endevours.

Comment: Nice answer, I've made a working fiddle of your code for people to see http://jsfiddle.net/v2pjfp7r/

Comment: "<3" This is essential info that should be part of the google documentation.

Comment: This is the info I needed! If you're creating your SVG in Illustrator (after following the advice about viewBox above), make sure you use "Save As…" then save it as an SVG, "Export for Screens…" won't work.

Comment: This is the perfect answer - helped me solve an issue where the marker was drifting on zoom. Turned out to be caused by the anchor point not being set in the correct coordinate system.

Answer (score 13):

Yes you can use an .svg file for the icon just like you can .png or another image file format. Just set the url of the icon to the directory where the .svg file is located. For example:

```
var icon = {
        url: 'path/to/images/car.svg',
        size: new google.maps.Size(sizeX, sizeY),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(sizeX/2, sizeY/2)
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        icon: icon
});
```

Comment: The icon object you are showing is for a standard marker, not an SVG marker. An svg marker uses properties of the symbol class, which are then assigned as the icon property of the marker class. (see MrUpsidown icon object for a correct reference...)

Comment: This will also break if the SVG has more than one 'd' path (usually associated with more than one layer in the svg image).

Comment: Note that your svg file should explicitly set the dimensions of the icon like so: `width="33px" height="50px"` - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21783089/165673

Answer (score 13):

Things are going better, right now you can use SVG files.

```
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: 36.720426, lng: -4.412573},
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            icon: "img/tree.svg"
        });
```

Comment: doesn't allow for rotation

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by others in this thread, don't forget to **explicitly set the width and height** attributes in the svg like so:

```
<svg id="some_id" data-name="some_name" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     viewBox="0 0 26 42"
     width="26px" height="42px">
```

if you don't do that no js manipulation can help you as gmaps will not have a frame of reference and always use a standard size.

*(i know it has been mentioned in some comments, but they are easy to miss. This information helped me in various cases)*

Answer (score 0):

OK! I done this soon in my web,I try two ways to create the custom google map marker, this run code use canvg.js is the best compatibility for browser.the Commented-Out Code is not support IE11 urrently.

```js
var marker;
var CustomShapeCoords = [16, 1.14, 21, 2.1, 25, 4.2, 28, 7.4, 30, 11.3, 30.6, 15.74, 25.85, 26.49, 21.02, 31.89, 15.92, 43.86, 10.92, 31.89, 5.9, 26.26, 1.4, 15.74, 2.1, 11.3, 4, 7.4, 7.1, 4.2, 11, 2.1, 16, 1.14];

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {
      lat: 59.325,
      lng: 18.070
    }
  });
  var markerOption = {
    latitude: 59.327,
    longitude: 18.067,
    color: "#" + "000",
    text: "ha"
  };
  marker = createMarker(markerOption);
  marker.setMap(map);
  marker.addListener('click', changeColorAndText);
};

function changeColorAndText() {
  var iconTmpObj = createSvgIcon( "#c00", "ok" );
  marker.setOptions( {
                icon: iconTmpObj
            } );
};

function createMarker(options) {
  //IE MarkerShape has problem
  var markerObj = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: createSvgIcon(options.color, options.text),
    position: {
      lat: parseFloat(options.latitude),
      lng: parseFloat(options.longitude)
    },
    draggable: false,
    visible: true,
    zIndex: 10,
    shape: {
      coords: CustomShapeCoords,
      type: 'poly'
    }
  });

  return markerObj;
};

function createSvgIcon(color, text) {
  var div = $("<div></div>");

  var svg = $(
    '<svg width="32px" height="43px"  viewBox="0 0 32 43" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
    '<path style="fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#020202;stroke-width:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M30.6,15.737c0-8.075-6.55-14.6-14.6-14.6c-8.075,0-14.601,6.55-14.601,14.6c0,4.149,1.726,7.875,4.5,10.524c1.8,1.801,4.175,4.301,5.025,5.625c1.75,2.726,5,11.976,5,11.976s3.325-9.25,5.1-11.976c0.825-1.274,3.05-3.6,4.825-5.399C28.774,23.813,30.6,20.012,30.6,15.737z"/>' +
    '<circle style="fill:' + color + ';" cx="16" cy="16" r="11"/>' +
    '<text x="16" y="20" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:10px;fill:#FFFFFF;">' + text + '</text>' +
    '</svg>'
  );
  div.append(svg);

  var dd = $("<canvas height='50px' width='50px'></cancas>");

  var svgHtml = div[0].innerHTML;

  canvg(dd[0], svgHtml);

  var imgSrc = dd[0].toDataURL("image/png");
  //"scaledSize" and "optimized: false" together seems did the tricky ---IE11  &&  viewBox influent IE scaledSize
  //var svg = '<svg width="32px" height="43px"  viewBox="0 0 32 43" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">'
  //    + '<path style="fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#020202;stroke-width:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M30.6,15.737c0-8.075-6.55-14.6-14.6-14.6c-8.075,0-14.601,6.55-14.601,14.6c0,4.149,1.726,7.875,4.5,10.524c1.8,1.801,4.175,4.301,5.025,5.625c1.75,2.726,5,11.976,5,11.976s3.325-9.25,5.1-11.976c0.825-1.274,3.05-3.6,4.825-5.399C28.774,23.813,30.6,20.012,30.6,15.737z"/>'
  //    + '<circle style="fill:' + color + ';" cx="16" cy="16" r="11"/>'
  //    + '<text x="16" y="20" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:10px;fill:#FFFFFF;">' + text + '</text>'
  //    + '</svg>';
  //var imgSrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svg);

  var iconObj = {
    size: new google.maps.Size(32, 43),
    url: imgSrc,
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 43)
  };

  return iconObj;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Your Custom Marker </title>
  <style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://canvg.github.io/canvg/canvg.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -5):

You need to pass `optimized: false`.

E.g.

```
var img = { url: 'img/puff.svg', scaledSide: new google.maps.Size(5, 5) };
new google.maps.Marker({position: this.mapOptions.center, map: this.map, icon: img, optimized: false,});
```

Without passing `optimized: false`, my svg appeared as a static image.