# for a google map marker is it possible to incorporate more than one color in an svg

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, svg, google-maps-markers

so what iv been trying to do for like two days now is.

```
    var arr = [
               {
                   path: "M239.68,331.38c34.206,58.142,87.12,150.48,87.12,150.48s49.609-84.922,88.56-149.76C327.52,275.94,241.84,326.34,239.68,331.38z",
                   fillColor: 'red',
                   fillOpacity: 1,
                   anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                   strokeWeight: 0,
                   scale: .6,
               },
               {
                   path: "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z",
                   fillColor: 'black',
                   fillOpacity: 1,
                   anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                   strokeWeight: 0,
                   scale: .6,
               }
              ];
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: location,
                  map: map,
                  draggable: false,
                  icon: arr,
                  zIndex: -20,

              });
```

so basically what iv been trying to do is to dynamically build an svg by combining two or more svgs and using that as a marker, is this possible at all? does anyone know? the only important property i want to style is the color, so that i have a marker with more than one color.

Comment: this has to be dynamically created, so coloring the svgs before hand wont be an option

Comment: you are not using SVG in your code, that's just "svg notation", subtle but important difference

Comment: have a look at the first answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413766/how-to-use-svg-markers-in-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: ah sorry, still roughly new to this. i have actually looked at the answer in your link before.  the problem is, that in that example its one markers with one svg notation path with one color.  what i want is one marker with two or more augmented paths, and the augmented path needs to be a different color

Comment: Have a look at this then - http://jsfiddle.net/32obcby0/ - I got the svg file, converted to a data uri and used that as the icon URL - HINT: the data URI doesn't have to come from an external file

Comment: ok sorry im still a little confused. the fact that your using a uri, would mean that you already have the icon ready to use, i need to assemble mine out of colors the user gives me.  unless your saying save it in variable, but then the question would be what syntax would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the html you'll see your "svg notation" converted to an actual SVG

There are many libraries you can use that make creating SVG's a little easier, or you can learn how to create them directly in javascript ... it's easier than you think - but I hard coded it - you can easily change the colors in the SVG using standard DOM getElementById etc -

for example, see how the original colours are red and black and the line

```
document.getElementById('p1').setAttribute('fill','green');
```

set's the red bit to green -

```js
var map;
var polyLine;
var polyOptions;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0)
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

        addPoint(event);
    });
}

function addPoint(event) {
    document.getElementById('p1').setAttribute('fill','green');
 var iconUrl = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8," + escape(document.getElementById("marker").innerHTML)
    var icon = {
        url: iconUrl,
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40,55)
    }

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        icon: icon,
        zIndex : -20
    });
}

initialize();
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&x=.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="height:400px"></div>
<div id='marker' style='display:none'><svg 
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    width="110mm" height="150mm" 
    id="svg111" 
    version="1.1">
<path id="p1"
    fill="red"
    fill-opacity="1"
    stroke-weight="0" 
    d="M239.68,331.38c34.206,58.142,87.12,150.48,87.12,150.48s49.609-84.922,88.56-149.76C327.52,275.94,241.84,326.34,239.68,331.38z" />
<path id="p2"
    fill="black"
    fill-opacity="1"
    stroke-weight="0" 
    d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
    </svg></div>
```

Comment: that my dear man is quite an impressive piece of work. thanks a bunch man