# Getting svg symbol for google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, svg

I am using an animation on Google Map in which a plane moves from one coordinate to another, the plane symbol is an SVG.

```
var planeSymbol = {
    path: 'M362.985,430.724l-10.248,51.234l62.332,57.969l-3.293,26.145 l-71.345-23.599l-2.001,13.069l-2.057-13.529l-71.278,22.928l-5.762-23.984l64.097-59.271l-8.913-51.359l0.858-114.43 l-21.945-11.338l-189.358,88.76l-1.18-32.262l213.344-180.08l0.875-107.436l7.973-32.005l7.642-12.054l7.377-3.958l9.238,3.65 l6.367,14.925l7.369,30.363v106.375l211.592,182.082l-1.496,32.247l-188.479-90.61l-21.616,10.087l-0.094,115.684',
    scale: 0.085,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeColor: '#000',
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(340, 340)
};
```

I want to change this icon into a car.

My question is how do I create this one? Or can I use my custom image for this?

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Car_with_Driver-Silhouette.svg

Comment: This has been answered in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413766/how-to-use-svg-markers-in-google-maps-api-v3).