# Google maps marker as SVG (with image png tag inside)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg

Is it possible to use .png image inside SVG block as google maps marker? I want to have one picture and draw it in different colors with SVG filter so then use as google markers.

I am trying to use picture without filter at least for now:

```
var svg = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
          '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="200px" width="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">' +
          '<image width="200" height="200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" xlink:href="{link.to.png.image}"/>' +
          '</svg>';

var icon = {
  url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,' + svg,
  scaledSize: iconSize // scaled size
};
```

And if I will take svg code and try to use it just via browser it renders ok

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="200px" width="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
<image width="200" height="200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" xlink:href="{link.to.png.image}"/>
</svg>
```

But it shows nothing while trying to use with google maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no success with embeding a PNG directly using it's URL, in a SVG marker for google maps. I tryied both http and https.

But, it works if you encode the binary file as data-uri :

```js
var svg = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
          '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="200px" width="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">' +
          '<image width="200" height="200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/>' +
          '</svg>';
```

Comment: May this conversion to data uri be done by some tool from the box (Javascript or smth like this) ?

Comment: @A.Khvorov : yes but that's another question. You can look  [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript) and try the code from Kaiido, as suggested in the accepted answer, or the answer from MuniR if you don't need an 'img' tag for this image in your html.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I found a older Question that might help you.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413766/how-to-use-svg-markers-in-google-maps-api-v3)

```
var markercolor = "#fff";
var icon = {
   path: "M-20,0a20,20 0 1,0 40,0a20,20 0 1,0 -40,0",
   fillColor: markercolor,
   fillOpacity: .6,
   anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
   strokeWeight: 0,
   scale: 1
}

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    icon: icon
});
```

I think the best way is to convert your .png in a .svg with a [online converter](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg) or something similar. 
Is there any reason why you need a .png?

Comment: In those answer ppl are using coordinates instead of png file. Path to my picture is stored in db (and for all ther pictures as well) so I need to pick up png file stored under file system and then show as google marker, but the point is that I need to color those png file in different colors depends on "category" and I decided to use SVG`s filter tag

Comment: The convert site i showed you has an API. You can use this to convert it direct in your code.

Comment: I found this 2 maybe it will help you:
https://github.com/jankovicsandras/imagetracerjs