# Custom SVG markers won't display in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3, svg, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to display some bus routes using ***Google Data Layer***, and then add some custom icon markers. Works great in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE 11 I only get the routes. I get an ***InvalidStateError*** somewhere deep in some obfuscated code.

the markers use a data uri with some inline SVG that is converted to base 64 strings. I've also tried NOT converting to base 64; that doesn't generate any apparent errors, but the markers still don't display.

Simplified javascript is pasted below, and you can see it in action at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ignotus0001/qnaeeouy/7).

```
    var map;

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: {lat: 38.813605, lng: -89.957399}
    });

    var geoJsonRoutesUrl = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/gtfs-test/MCT-All-Bus-Routes.json';

    var routesLayer = new google.maps.Data(); 
    routesLayer.loadGeoJson(geoJsonRoutesUrl);
    routesLayer.setMap(map);  
    routesLayer.setStyle(function(feature) {
      return ({
        strokeColor: feature.getProperty('color'),
      fillColor: feature.getProperty('color'),
        strokeWeight: 6
      });
    });

    var geoJsonRouteMarkersUrl = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/gtfs-test/MCT-All-Bus-Route-Markers.json';
    var routeMarkersLayer = new google.maps.Data(); 
    routeMarkersLayer.loadGeoJson(geoJsonRouteMarkersUrl);
    routeMarkersLayer.setMap(map);
    routeMarkersLayer.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var markerIcon = CreateRouteMarkersIconDefinition(
        feature.getProperty('route'),
        feature.getProperty('color'),
        feature.getProperty('backColor'));
      return ({icon: markerIcon});
    });


  function CreateRouteMarkersIconDefinition(route, color, backColor) {
    var svgHtml = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30">';
    svgHtml += '<ellipse cx="15" cy="15" r="15" rx="15" ry="10" fill="' +  backColor + '" />';
    svgHtml += '<text x="15" y="20" style="text-anchor: middle;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="12px" font-weight = "bold" fill="' + color + '" >' + route + '</text>';
    svgHtml += '</svg>';
    var svgIcon = {
      url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8;base64,' + btoa(svgHtml),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 15)
    };

    return svgIcon;
  }
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I use regular svgs as map markers and get the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 26):

I had a similar problem, and eventually found that you can get SVG and data URI SVG images working, but some parameters that aren't required for other image types are required for SVG.
Specifically, once I size and scaledSize parameters on the definition for the icon (along with uri, origin and anchor values), the error went away and the marker rendered.
My sample marker is as follows (with svg having already been defined to be the SVG I want as the marker):

```
var bubbleImage = {
              url: 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + Base64.encode(svg),
              size: new google.maps.Size(192, 21),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(192,21),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(88, 53)
          };
          var bubbleMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: feature.position,
              icon: bubbleImage,
              map: window.map,
              optimized: false,
              zIndex: 1
          });
```

Comment: "scaledSize" and "optimized: false" together seems did the tricky.

Comment: had this problem with IE11 and svg images as files (ordinary url , not dataURIs), so it's not specific to data URIs. @Morio is correct that the two required bits seem to be scaledSize and optimized.  Origin, anchor, and size were not required for me.

Comment: I can verify that this fixed an SVG error I was getting on IE11 on win8: InvalidStateError.  Specifically setting scaledSize on the icon hash and optimized:false on the hash passed to the Marker constructor.

Comment: This partially works. addListener mouseover/mouseouts to change/alter the marker cause an error on IE 11-- XML5602: Unexpected end of input. Line: 1, Column 1041. Where on Chrome it works just fine.

Comment: @MikeKormendy sure it's not a trailing comma in an object literal?

Comment: @BjörnAliGöransson yup sure it wasnt.

Comment: Worked for me, this should be marked as the correct answer!

Answer (score 2):

[This reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) in MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) states that "Internet Explorer 8 and above only supports data URIs for images in CSS, , and ". I guess this just isn't supported in IE. What else is new?

Comment: No, this is definetely working in IE11 for google maps.

Comment: Again, this actually works. See @morio's comment on David Burton's answer; the key is to have both "scaledSize" and "optimized: false" in there.

Answer (score -1):

OK! I done this in my web,I used it in my angularJS project, I share it use Jquery. I try two ways to create the custom google map marker, this run code use canvg.js is the best compatibility for browser.the Commented-Out Code is not support IE11 urrently("scaledSize" and "optimized: false" together seems did the tricky).

```js
var marker;
var CustomShapeCoords = [16, 1.14, 21, 2.1, 25, 4.2, 28, 7.4, 30, 11.3, 30.6, 15.74, 25.85, 26.49, 21.02, 31.89, 15.92, 43.86, 10.92, 31.89, 5.9, 26.26, 1.4, 15.74, 2.1, 11.3, 4, 7.4, 7.1, 4.2, 11, 2.1, 16, 1.14];

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {
      lat: 59.325,
      lng: 18.070
    }
  });
  var markerOption = {
    latitude: 59.327,
    longitude: 18.067,
    color: "#" + "000",
    text: "ha"
  };
  marker = createMarker(markerOption);
  marker.setMap(map);
  marker.addListener('click', changeColorAndText);
};

function changeColorAndText() {
  var iconTmpObj = createSvgIcon( "#c00", "ok" );
  marker.setOptions( {
                icon: iconTmpObj
            } );
};

function createMarker(options) {
  //IE MarkerShape has problem
  var markerObj = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: createSvgIcon(options.color, options.text),
    position: {
      lat: parseFloat(options.latitude),
      lng: parseFloat(options.longitude)
    },
    draggable: false,
    visible: true,
    zIndex: 10,
    shape: {
      coords: CustomShapeCoords,
      type: 'poly'
    }
  });

  return markerObj;
};

function createSvgIcon(color, text) {
  var div = $("<div></div>");

  var svg = $(
    '<svg width="32px" height="43px"  viewBox="0 0 32 43" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
    '<path style="fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#020202;stroke-width:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M30.6,15.737c0-8.075-6.55-14.6-14.6-14.6c-8.075,0-14.601,6.55-14.601,14.6c0,4.149,1.726,7.875,4.5,10.524c1.8,1.801,4.175,4.301,5.025,5.625c1.75,2.726,5,11.976,5,11.976s3.325-9.25,5.1-11.976c0.825-1.274,3.05-3.6,4.825-5.399C28.774,23.813,30.6,20.012,30.6,15.737z"/>' +
    '<circle style="fill:' + color + ';" cx="16" cy="16" r="11"/>' +
    '<text x="16" y="20" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:10px;fill:#FFFFFF;">' + text + '</text>' +
    '</svg>'
  );
  div.append(svg);

  var dd = $("<canvas height='50px' width='50px'></cancas>");

  var svgHtml = div[0].innerHTML;

  canvg(dd[0], svgHtml);

  var imgSrc = dd[0].toDataURL("image/png");
  //"scaledSize" and "optimized: false" together seems did the tricky ---IE11  &&  viewBox influent IE scaledSize
  //var svg = '<svg width="32px" height="43px"  viewBox="0 0 32 43" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">'
  //    + '<path style="fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#020202;stroke-width:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M30.6,15.737c0-8.075-6.55-14.6-14.6-14.6c-8.075,0-14.601,6.55-14.601,14.6c0,4.149,1.726,7.875,4.5,10.524c1.8,1.801,4.175,4.301,5.025,5.625c1.75,2.726,5,11.976,5,11.976s3.325-9.25,5.1-11.976c0.825-1.274,3.05-3.6,4.825-5.399C28.774,23.813,30.6,20.012,30.6,15.737z"/>'
  //    + '<circle style="fill:' + color + ';" cx="16" cy="16" r="11"/>'
  //    + '<text x="16" y="20" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:10px;fill:#FFFFFF;">' + text + '</text>'
  //    + '</svg>';
  //var imgSrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svg);

  var iconObj = {
    size: new google.maps.Size(32, 43),
    url: imgSrc,
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 43)
  };

  return iconObj;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Your Custom Marker </title>
  <style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://canvg.github.io/canvg/canvg.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
</body>

</html>
```