# Google Maps API MarkerOptions Icon SVG not url

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, svg

Google Maps API's MarkerOptions object specification (google.maps.MarkerOptions) icon property Type: string is only treated as though it were an Icon with the string as a url.

Is there anyway around this? I have an svg that changes dynamically due to incoming data and logic and therefore have a SVG string here, but it's not a url and not an url of an imported in svg file.

Can I override MarkerOptions icon property somehow?

There is too much code to type here but here is an object within the markers array:

```
const markers = [
  {
    position: {lat: 28.3422, lng: -80.6112},
    key: 'Truckee',
    defaultAnimation: 0,
    valuationType: 'VALUE_CONCLUSION',
    showInfo: false,
    infoContent: infoContent,
    icon: iconService(valuation)
  }
```

]

if the icon value is '/static/media/comparable-sale.cb717259.svg' the marker will render with that image, but if iconService(valuation) returns a string that isn't a url :

`<svg width=22 px height=26 px viewBox=0 0 22 26><g stroke=none strokeWidth=1 fill=none fillRule=evenodd><path d=M10.5,24 C11.2054469,24 20,15.5173578 20,10.3522518 C20,5.18714574 15.7467051,1 10.5,1 C5.25329488,1 1,5.18714574 1,10.3522518 C1,15.5173578 9.79455308,24 10.5,24 Z stroke=#FFC220 strokeWidth=1.5 fill=#FFC220></path> <textfill=#FFC220 x=50% y=50% textAnchor=middle fontWeight=700 fontSize=12px transform=translate(-0.3, 2.5) fontFamily='Lato', sans-serif> null</text></g></svg>`

It will not render the icon as the marker and the marker remains there but without the SVG style.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass [Symbol](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols) object with the path returned from `iconService(valuation)` to the marker's `icon` property.

Comment: That does work if given a simple path, for ex:

'M24.5 9h-8.1l-2.9-7.7C13.4 1.1 13.2 1 13 1c-0.2 0-0.4 0.1-0.5 0.3L9.6 9H1.5C1.3 9 1.1 9.1 1 9.3 1 9.5 1 9.8 1.2 9.9l6.7 5.8L5 24.3c-0.1 0.2 0 0.4 0.2 0.6 0.2 0.1 0.4 0.1 0.6 0l7.2-5.3 7.2 5.3c0.1 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.3 0.1 0.1 0 0.2 0 0.3-0.1 0.2-0.1 0.2-0.4 0.2-0.6l-2.9-8.7 6.7-5.8C25 9.8 25 9.5 25 9.3 24.9 9.1 24.7 9 24.5 9z'

 but the entirety of the SVG shown above passed to it isn't. And I'm still not sure why.

Comment: Proposed solution requires extraction of path from SVG. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30890373/634386) answer could be helpful if you really want to use full SVG.